# Get only score value in pylint

Tags: python, pylint

`Pylint <package-to-scan>` will generate analysis and score.

I checked all the command-line options. There is no option that just returns score value e.g. 7.5 or 7.5/10

Also checked programmatically, For example, there is no option in `epylint.py_run` for getting only score.

Is saving stdout and then finding score via regex the only option?

Comment: I think you could check their issue tracker and file a bug report.